# Personal chess database

Tags: software, database, linux

I'm looking for non commercial program where I can import PGNs. And to visualize the games I want simple GUI and analysis-table like you will find [here](http://chessok.com/?page_id=352). Additionally it would be nice if the program provides an interface where I can write my own statistics.

What I found was [gnu chess](https://www.gnu.org/software/chess/), [sunfish](https://github.com/thomasahle/sunfish) and [jose](http://jose-chess.sourceforge.net/). But those programs are more then I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SCID](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) does everything you are looking for, it's great chess database software.

Answer (score 0):

[Lichess](https://database.lichess.org) has everything you need. It also updates a new list every month so the database always grows. Currently it has over 2,000,000,000 games. All in a pgn file. They also publish issues they have recorded to help people resolve their code. One more thing Lichess has is not only standard chess but also variants and puzzles all of which are separate and update monthly.